# Why is modulus defined the way it is in programming languages

Tags: math, language-agnostic, language-design, modulus

I'm not asking about the definition but rather why the language creators chose to define modulus with asymmetric behavior in C++. (I think Java too)

Suppose I want to find the least number greater than or equal to n that is divisible by f.

If n is positive, then I do:

```
if(n % f)
   ans = n + f - n % f;
```

If n is negative:

```
ans = n - n % f;
```

Clearly, this definition is not the most expedient when dealing with negative and positive numbers. So why was it defined like this? In what case does it yield expediency?

Comment: Are you asking why modulo doesn't have a fixed definition for negative operands?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: To clarify: I'm asking why the definition is asymmetric with respect to the parity of the first operand.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's using "modulo 2 arithmetic", where each binary digit is treated independently of the other.  Look at the example on "division" [here](http://booster911.hubpages.com/hub/Modulo-2-Arithmetic)

Comment: But it isn't. Modulo-2 arithmetic is used when calculating CRCs, not the modulus operator.

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken. When `n` is negative, C++ allows the result of the modulus operator to be either negative or positive as long as the results from `%` and `/` are consistent, so for any given `a` and `b`, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` will always yield `a`. C99 requires that the result of `a % b` will have the same sign as `a`. Some other languages (e.g., Python) require that the sign of `a % b` have the same sign as `b`.

This means the expression you've given for negative `n` is not actually required to work in C++. When/if `n%f` yields a positive number (even though `n` is negative), it will give `ans` that's less than `n`.

Comment: `(a/b)*b + a%b` always yields `a` except if `b` is zero, then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: *"When n is negative, ...*" Better said, the result is implementation defined in C++03 if either the dividend or divisor is negative. However, most C++ compilers follow the C99 convention; this lets the vendor use the same machinery for C and C++ code. C++11 follows the C99 convention. It is no longer implementation defined.

Comment: @David: I considered pointing out that *either* operand being negative led to implementation defined results -- but since he'd talked specifically about `n` being negative, decided it was better discuss only that. As far as the similarity goes, C99 is more the follower than the leader -- i.e., they standardized it because essentially all modern hardware works that way. Microsoft, for one example, seems to use what the x86 `div` instruction produces, and shows no apparent interest in C99 conformance.

Comment: I wonder how often the standards-mandated behavior is more useful than would be "If either operand to the integral divide or modulus operator is negative, the result shall be unspecified"?  Such a spec would speed up implementations on processors which lack a signed-divide instruction [common in the world of embedded-systems].  I guess in situations where exactness doesn't really matter specifying that the quotient will be less than a unit away from the rational number defined by the division may be better than e.g. performing the divide as unsigned, but I wish there were a nice way...

Comment: ...to request proper modulus and round-to-negative division operations.

Comment: Incidentally, if `i` is a signed integer, computations like `i/16` and `i%16` could be performed faster using round-to-negative-infinity semantics on the division than using the standards-mandated semantics.